# Assign enum value to variable

Tags: typescript, enums

I have an issue, why this is not possible and how to solve it

```
enum Cars {
    FORD='Ford',
    KIA='KIA'
}

class MyCars {
    public carName: typeof Cars =Cars;
}

const car1 = new MyCars();
car1.carName = Cars.FORD;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `carName` typing is incorrect. Your code fixed:

```
enum Cars {
    FORD='Ford',
    KIA='KIA'
}

class MyCars {
    public carName?: Cars;
}

const car1 = new MyCars();
car1.carName = Cars.FORD;
```

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAwghgJwM5QN4CgpagMQPIBKAIgLwDkOA9ggCZkA0m2A0gJICC5b7Z6AvunQBjADZwkKALIBPeMjRMsABzAAjEQEshUIYgBycCMAD8ALliIkAbn6ChlEEgAuOxAEYoJKCGAB3KDJySAAUAJQ2ughuAHSRBkaeFsjR%20MRWQA)